# SQL Join - Get each User once and show specific assignments

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's my table structure:

```
users
--userid
--firstname
--lastname

users_task
--userid
--taskid
```

I'd like to show each user once and the id's for a specific assignment. The results should look something like this:

```
FirstName | LastName | Users_Task.UserID | TaskID  
John        Doe        Null                Null
Suzy        Doe        101                 39
```

I've made a query that works but if I specify task 38 then Suzy Doe does not show up in the results because she is not null or 38. I need each user to show up once, every time.

Here's my actual SQL. Sorry about the vb variable in the WHERE statement:

```
SELECT users.userid AS UserUserID, users.firstname AS UserFirstName, 
    users.lastname AS UserLastName, 
    issue_assigneduser.issueid as AssignedIssueID, 
    issue_assigneduser.userid as AssignedUserID 
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN
    issue_assigneduser ON users.userid = issue_assigneduser.userid
WHERE (users.disabledyn = 0 AND (issueid Is Null or issueid = " & iIssueID & "))
ORDER BY UserFirstName, UserLastName
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 but I'm assuming and hoping that the solution will be fairly generic.

Comment: Are they being filtered out by your `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your issueid in the join, not there where

```
SELECT users.userid AS UserUserID, users.firstname AS UserFirstName, 
    users.lastname AS UserLastName, 
    issue_assigneduser.issueid as AssignedIssueID, 
    issue_assigneduser.userid as AssignedUserID 
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN
    issue_assigneduser ON users.userid = issue_assigneduser.userid
    AND (issueid Is Null or issueid = " & iIssueID & ")
WHERE users.disabledyn = 0 
ORDER BY UserFirstName, UserLastName
```

At this point, you can probably even get away with

```
SELECT users.userid AS UserUserID, users.firstname AS UserFirstName, 
    users.lastname AS UserLastName, 
    issue_assigneduser.issueid as AssignedIssueID, 
    issue_assigneduser.userid as AssignedUserID 
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN
    issue_assigneduser ON users.userid = issue_assigneduser.userid
    AND issueid = " & iIssueID & "
WHERE users.disabledyn = 0 
ORDER BY UserFirstName, UserLastName
```

Comment: Why not grab at the opportunity of showing someone the benefits of using short table aliases? :) Anyway, you are right, filtering the joined table in the WHERE clause effectively turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN, so moving it to the ON clause resolves the issue, +1.

Comment: This is one of the biggest issues I see with people that are new to SQL.  It makes me wonder why more tutorials don't mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT users.userid AS UserUserID, users.firstname AS UserFirstName, 
    users.lastname AS UserLastName, 
    issue_assigneduser.issueid as AssignedIssueID, 
    issue_assigneduser.userid as AssignedUserID 
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN
    issue_assigneduser 
    ON users.userid = issue_assigneduser.userid
    AND (issueid Is Null or issueid = " & iIssueID & ")
WHERE (users.disabledyn = 0)
ORDER BY UserFirstName, UserLastName
```

Including the criteria in the WHERE clause forced an INNER JOIN, even though you specified LEFT.